# Latin for "Teaching man"

Tags: vocabulary, scientific-names, latin-to-english-translation

How would you say "teaching man" in Latin, in the same way as "homo sapiens" (thinking man) or "homo economicus" (economic man)? It would be for an essay discussing modern education and the role of a teacher, as if one were looking at an "exhibit" of a species that is "teaching man".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A straightforward translation is ***Homō docēns***. (Macrons are optional; they represent a difference in sound which disappeared in later Latin.)

*Homō* is a straightforward word for "human". *Docēns* is the present participle of *doceō*, a straightforward word for "to teach". See [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddoceo) for more information on the latter.

There are a few other words for "teach": *ērudiō* "educate", *īnstruō* "instruct", *moneō* "advise". But *doceō* is the most straightforward, and I think the best suited to your purpose.